# Cannot borrow self twice in one function call

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm a newbie in `rust`, and stunned with making function call.
I'm sorry for I cannot make clean error example, as error occurs in the constructor of `iced::PickList`.

The matter is — as long as I use only one method in that call — the build pass and programm works, but if I just change the signature of the second needed method for be not static — I can not build and fix bowwor errors at all.

The complete working (builds and launches) example on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8dae63fba67c21df0bef238b8f2a50ef).

While it looks like this, with `Self::port_names()` call, it works.

```
extern crate iced;
extern crate midir;

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use std::option::Option::Some;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};

use iced::{
    button, executor, pick_list, scrollable, Align, Application, Button, Column, Command,
    Container, Element, Length, PickList, Scrollable, Settings, Space, Text,
};
use midir::{Ignore, MidiInput, MidiInputConnection, MidiInputPort, MidiInputPorts};

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Port {
    pub index: usize,
}

struct BigNote {
    note: i32,
    need_init: bool,
    client_name: String,
    scroll: scrollable::State,
    ports_list: pick_list::State<Port>,
    selected_port: Port,

    connection: Option<MidiInputConnection<Sender<Vec<u8>>>>,
}

impl BigNote {
    fn midi_in(&self) -> MidiInput {
        MidiInput::new(&self.client_name.to_string()).unwrap()
    }
    fn ports_names() -> Vec<Port> {  // this is static method
        let mut names: Vec<Port> = Vec::new();
        names.push(Port { index: 0 });
        names.push(Port { index: 1 });
        names.into()
    }
}

impl Application for BigNote {
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Message = Message;
    type Flags = ();

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (BigNote, Command<self::Message>) {
        (
            BigNote {
                note: -1,
                need_init: true,
                client_name: String::from("MyBigNote"),
                connection: Option::None,
                ports_list: pick_list::State::<Port>::default(),
                scroll: scrollable::State::default(),
                selected_port: Port { index: 1 },
            },
            Command::none(),
        )
    }

    fn view(&mut self) -> Element<Message> {
        let pick_list = PickList::new(
            &mut self.ports_list,
            Self::ports_names(),  // here is static method
            Some(self.selected_port.clone()),
            Message::PortSelected,
        );

        let mut content = Scrollable::new(&mut self.scroll)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .align_items(Align::Center)
            .spacing(10)
            .push(Space::with_height(Length::Units(600)))
            .push(Text::new("Which is your favorite String?"))
            .push(pick_list);

        content = content.push(Space::with_height(Length::Units(600)));

        Container::new(content)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .height(Length::Fill)
            .center_x()
            .center_y()
            .into()
    }
}
```

If I just replace the method signature — problems begin from «immutable borrow can not be performed along with mutable» until «temporary resource cannot be returned from function».

```
extern crate iced;
extern crate midir;

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use std::option::Option::Some;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};

use iced::{
    button, executor, pick_list, scrollable, Align, Application, Button, Column, Command,
    Container, Element, Length, PickList, Scrollable, Settings, Space, Text,
};
use midir::{Ignore, MidiInput, MidiInputConnection, MidiInputPort, MidiInputPorts};

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Port {
    pub index: usize,
}

struct BigNote {
    note: i32,
    need_init: bool,
    client_name: String,
    scroll: scrollable::State,
    ports_list: pick_list::State<Port>,
    selected_port: Port,

    connection: Option<MidiInputConnection<Sender<Vec<u8>>>>,
}

impl BigNote {
    fn midi_in(&self) -> MidiInput {
        MidiInput::new(&self.client_name.to_string()).unwrap()
    }
    fn ports_names(&self) -> Vec<Port> { // here is change
        let mut names: Vec<Port> = Vec::new();
        names.push(Port { index: 0 });
        names.push(Port { index: 1 });
        names.into()
    }
}

impl Application for BigNote {
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Message = Message;
    type Flags = ();

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (BigNote, Command<self::Message>) {
        (
            BigNote {
                note: -1,
                need_init: true,
                client_name: String::from("MyBigNote"),
                connection: Option::None,
                ports_list: pick_list::State::<Port>::default(),
                scroll: scrollable::State::default(),
                selected_port: Port { index: 1 },
            },
            Command::none(),
        )
    }

    fn view(&mut self) -> Element<Message> {
        let pick_list = PickList::new(
            &mut self.ports_list,
            self.ports_names(),  // and here
            Some(self.selected_port.clone()),
            Message::PortSelected,
        );

        let mut content = Scrollable::new(&mut self.scroll)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .align_items(Align::Center)
            .spacing(10)
            .push(Space::with_height(Length::Units(600)))
            .push(Text::new("Which is your favorite String?"))
            .push(pick_list);

        content = content.push(Space::with_height(Length::Units(600)));

        Container::new(content)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .height(Length::Fill)
            .center_x()
            .center_y()
            .into()
    }
}
```

Please, help me understand why is it happens and how to avoid such problems.

[EDIT]

I feel, I still don't get the fundamental concept of the variable\local variable in rust, as when i changed my `view` function to this:

```
fn view(&mut self) -> Element<Message> {
        let port_names = self.ports_names(); // method call now here
        let pick_list = PickList::new(
            &mut self.ports_list,
            port_names, // here only variable
            Some(self.selected_port.clone()),
            Message::PortSelected,
        );

        let mut content = Scrollable::new(&mut self.scroll)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .align_items(Align::Center)
            .spacing(10)
            .push(Space::with_height(Length::Units(600)))
            .push(Text::new("Which is your favorite String?"))
            .push(pick_list);

        content = content.push(Space::with_height(Length::Units(600)));

        Container::new(content)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .height(Length::Fill)
            .center_x()
            .center_y()
            .into()
    }
```

It worked.
I understand that the reason is — I moved direct method call to the local viable, but I can see no difference here for myself...

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a compound expression like a structure constructor or a function call,

```rust
        let pick_list = PickList::new(
            &mut self.ports_list,
            self.ports_names(),  // and here
            Some(self.selected_port.clone()),
            Message::PortSelected,
        );
```

evaluation of it proceeds in a very specific fashion: first, each of the argument expressions is evaluated, *in the order they're written in the source code,* and  their values are stored temporarily on the stack. Then, once all the argument values are ready, the function is called.

In this case:

1. `&mut self.ports_list` is evaluated first and stored as a temporary value. Now, `self.ports_list` is mutably borrowed.
2. `self.ports_names()` is evaluated second — but `self.ports_list` is mutably borrowed, and calling `ports_names` requires an immutable borrow of *all of `self`*, which is not allowed so there is a compile error.

   In the version that calls `Self::ports_names()`, there is no borrow of `self`, so this is permitted.
3. `Some(self.selected_port.clone())` is evaluated third, in the versions that compile successfully. Here, `self.selected_port` is a *different field* than `self.ports_list`, and the compiler understands that they may be safely borrowed separately.

> I moved direct method call to the local viable, but I can see no difference here for myself...

In general, you can have mutable borrows of *specific fields of a structure* at the same time as other borrows, but you cannot have a mutable borrow that *overlaps* with anything else — and a method call always borrows the entire structure, guaranteeing overlap.

The important difference in your third, working version is not that `self.ports_names()` is stored in a local variable, but that `self.ports_names()` is evaluated *before* `&mut self.ports_list` is evaluated. The local variable is just a convenience to make that happen.

For example, if `PickList` were a type of yours that you could write as a structure literal instead of calling a `new()` function, then you could write the field initializers in an order that doesn't conflict:

```rust
let pick_list = PickList {
    options: self.ports_names(),
    selected: Some(self.selected_port.clone()),
    on_selected: Message::PortSelected

    // Write this last and it doesn't conflict with any temporary immutable borrows above.
    state: &mut self.ports_list,
}
```